Восстановление вложений вк через VKAPI
Скачал архив вк, чтоб посмотреть удалённый диалог и вложения, некоторые фото открываются, а другие формата https://vk.com/im?sel=????&z=photo????_???? не возможно открыть, ошибка доступа. Как-то можно через VKAPI вывести это изображение? Диалог с человеком удалён и у него тоже.
